# Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2 failed oauth call access token: received error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: perl, google-sheets-api, google-authentication, google-oauth

I was following the solution in here: 
[Net::Google::AuthSub login failed with new Google Drive version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476405/netgoogleauthsub-login-failed-with-new-google-drive-version/)

However, at this line:

```
my $token = $oauth2->get_access_token($code) or die;
```

I am getting error below:

```
failed oauth call access token: received error: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

what could be the issue? Is it something in Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2 that I need to fix?
I am using Strawberry Perl in windows.

Edit: 
Below is my code:

```
my $oauth2 = Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2->new(
  client_id => 'XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret => 'XXXXXXXX',
  scope => ['http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/'],
);

my $url = $oauth2->authorize_url();
print "OAuth URL, get code: $url\n";
use Term::Prompt;
my $code = prompt('x', 'paste the code: ', '', ''); 

my $token = $oauth2->get_access_token($code) or die;
```

Comment: Are you pasting the code you got from your web browser exactly into your application?

Comment: Yes, the code starts with 4/ and ends with mwI. Total 77 characters.

Comment: Maybe Windows is interpreting the code before it gets copied to the `code` variable. Try pasting the code directly into your application, replacing the `$code = prompt(...)` line with `$code = "... paste from browser..."`.

Answer (score 0):

When I do this, I always get codes that start with 4/ and end with mwI#.  Maybe you're missing that last # character?

Comment: I added # to the end of the code, but still having the same error. 
Since I am getting to the Google page where it says "Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:", that means the client_id and client_secret should have been set correctly, right?

Is there any account setting that needs to be enabled beside the ones suggested in the solution page I referred to?

Comment: Hmm, not sure.  Can you post more of your code?  (Blank out the client_id and client_secret of course.)  You could also try your code on the OAuth Playground at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to see if you get a token there.

Comment: I put my code up above.
I went to OAuth Playground, the Response:
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    Content-length: 74
    X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    X-content-type-options: nosniff
    Expires: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 03:05:55 GMT
    Vary: Origin,X-Origin
    Server: GSE
    Cache-control: private, max-age=0
    Date: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 03:05:55 GMT
    X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
    {
      "error_description": "Unauthorized", 
      "error": "unauthorized_client"
    }

Comment: Scratch comment above, I was using the code from my script and trying to authorize OAuth Playground, of course it would say unauthorized client.

Comment: Looking at your code, the only difference from mine is that it required me to set `redirect_uri` as a parameter in the initial call to `Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2->new`.  But if you're getting a code back, you must be OK there.  I wonder if Edward Doolittle's comment above might be on the right track, that it's something about the `Term::Prompt` behavior in Windows that is messing things up.  Try having your script print the code back out after it reads it, and/or splitting your script in two (one to get the code, then the other in which you paste the code into your script hard-coded).

Comment: Just an update, I still have not able to get this to work, but today the old way of connecting to Google Spreadsheet with username and password works again for some reason.