# Perl : Exporting a Google Spreadsheet Into xlsx Format Using Net::Google::Drive

Tags: perl, google-docs

I am trying to export google spreasheets into xlsx excel spreasheets using Perl.

I am currently able to get the data in the google spreadsheet from my script but I'd prefer to export the file into a local excel spreadsheet and get the information I need from there.

I can't manage to find a way to export a google spreadsheet into a local xlsx file using Net::Google::Drive

Only binary files can be obtained with the methods in that module.

has anyone managed to perform this ?

If yes, could you share some code ?

Thanks and regards.

X.

--

Here is my current code :

```perl
    use Net::Google::Drive;
    use Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2;
    use Storable;

    my $client_id = "XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    my $client_secret = "YYYYY";

    my $oauth2 = Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2->new(
    client_id => $client_id,
    client_secret => $client_secret,
    scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
    );


    my $session = retrieve('google_drive.session');
    my $restored_token = Net::OAuth2::AccessToken->session_thaw($session,
    auto_refresh => 1,
    profile => $oauth2->oauth2_webserver,
    );

    $oauth2->access_token($restored_token);


     my $disk = Net::Google::Drive->new(
    -client_id => $client_id, 
    -client_secret => $client_secret,
    -access_token => $oauth2->access_token($restored_token),
    -refresh_token => $oauth2->refresh_token($restored_token),
    );


    my $file_id = "XXXXX";
    my $dest_file = 'd:\\test.xlsx';

    $disk->downloadFile(
    -file_id        => $file_id,
    -dest_file      => $dest_file,
    );
```

Comment: Please show the script you are using currently. I am trying to test this but I am not able to get the refresh token using `Net::Google::OAuth`

Comment: Hi, I pasted my code in the issue description. FYI, I used the following method to solve my oauth issues to access my gdrive documents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476405/netgoogleauthsub-login-failed-with-new-google-drive-version